# How to change direction in animation?

Tags: animation

I took the animation from Mixamo, animation aim, but it is not directed where I need it, I need to correct the animation and change its direction, for example, rotate the direction of the animation by 45 degrees.
How to do it?

[image]

Comment: one way would be to parent the armature to an empty and then just rotate that empty

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. create another bone and bind to it? (but let's say you can't add bones)
I have a root bone, it is rotated 45 degrees in the animation, but through editing, if you change it, the whole animation will rotate, you need to change every frame through the pose.
I don't really understand how to fix it yet...

Comment: if u provide a blend file i will try to show you (because every rig might be different and if i show you a "general" example it might not help you in your special case and i don't like to waste my time)

Comment: I just need to change the position (rotation) root bone so that it doesn't affect the rest of the animation...

Comment: 'Rotate the direction of animation' could mean quite  a few things... please illustrate what it means in your case.

Comment: I edited the post, in the screenshot the root bone is rotated 45 degrees, I need it to be rotated 0.
But if I rotate it, then the entire armature with animation will rotate, but how can I set it to 0 but at the same time so that the entire animation is not affected?